# Script becomes unresponsive when running from gnome keyboard shortcut

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome, gnome3, rofi

I have a shell script /usr/local/bin/myrofi.sh which contains:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/rofi -run-list-command ". /usr/local/bin/get_aliases.sh" -run-command "/usr/bin/zsh -i -c '{cmd}'" -show run
```

when I run this script from terminal it works perfectly, but when I run this from GNOME keyboard shortcut like:

[image]

then the system becomes unresponsive and it hangs the system. Then I will have to switch to login shell then run `killall rofi` to get back my normal system.

My system have Arch linux with Gnome window manager.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the full path of the script, i.e `/usr/local/bin/myrofi.sh`, in the "Command" input field to be able to run it using a shortcut.

Comment: No I have tried it, doesn't work. That GNOME keyboard shortcut is creating problem because of `-i` option in `/usr/bin/zsh -i -c '{cmd}'`. I switched to xbindkeys and it works perfectly.